# add int array to a 2d ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Anyone know how to add an `int[] array` into a 2d `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`?

The code...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] intArray = {1,1,1,1};
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(intArray))); // <- compile error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change your `int` array to an `Integer` array.

```
Integer [] intArray = {1,1,1,1};
```

Comment: The problem here is in my application, the arrays indexes get passed through multiple methods as an `int` for mutable changes and acquiring results. I was hoping to convert it just before it gets added to the 2d ArrayList. Is it possible to convert while adding it?

Comment: There is autoboxing from `int` to `Integer` but no autoboxing from `int[]` to `Integer[]`

Comment: you could leave it as type `int` and try this `list.add(Arrays.stream(intArray).boxed().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)));`

Comment: I see, so even though it worked with `String[] array = {"one","one","one","one"};` and `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = ArrayList<>();` and then `list.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(tempResult)))`... it only worked with this because `String` was the same type, and `int` and `Integer` are different and "can't be autoboxed from `int[]` to `Integer[]`"?

Comment: Yep, that is the jist

Comment: @Aominè code is same as post and yes I'm using java 1.8

Comment: @FiddleFreak ooops!, I forget to mention, the code I posted earlier was for java-8+ ^^.

Comment: @Scary Wombat this might be the best solution for the way my app handles all the changes. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Make your `ArrayList` an `ArrayList` of `int[]`:

```
ArrayList<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(intArray); // should work now
```